# History.js + Forms?

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js

We are migrating from [jQuery Ajaxy](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-ajaxy) to [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). Ajaxy has smart form managment. Does anyone have sample how to integrate History.js to process forms?

Comment: did you managed to find anything to how to work with forms and post action with history.js ? Please reply back.

Answer (score 0):

History.js is essentially a cross-browser shim that allows you use the HTML5 History API, and **it does not specifically provide any built-in form management logic**.  So if you wanted to use it to manage form states, you would have to manually add history entries to the browser history object like this:

```
// If the History.js plugin has been included on the page
if(window.History) {

    // Adds a new state and url to the browser history object
    // Eg. If your page was index.html... it becomes index.html?someState
    window.History.pushState(null, $(this).attr("data-href"), "?someState");

}
```

And if you had some custom logic that you needed to happen when a state change happened, you could do something like this:

```
// If the History.js plugin has been included on the page

    if(window.History) {

        // Binds to the StateChange Event
        window.History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {

            // Do something

        });
    }
```

For more information on History.js check out the [History.js github page](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/)